# Effective way of training the bot, language processing APIs

Tags: bots, botframework

I'm using Microsoft Bot Framework to build a bot which helps users answer the questions related to a specific topic. I have a list of these questions and correct answers for each question. I need to teach my bot these answers. So when user asks something similar, the bot should give a correct answer. What kind of nature language processing APIs can I use? I know about LUIS, and I  know how to build my own model using LUIS. But I'm not sure that I can train my bot in this way very well. Could you give me some directions regarding effective way of training the bot ? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LUIS, you can take advantage of one of the [Model Features](https://www.luis.ai/Help/#Performance): Phrase Lists, which will allow you to categorize similar words/phrase, and improve the performance of the training.